# converting '0'...'n' into '0' '1' up to 'n'

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm processing a text file that has a few statements of the form

```
'0'...'7'
```

or

```
'0'...'9'
```

or even

```
'a'...'j'
```

(the idiom '...' appears only in these structures) that I'd like to convert to statements of the form...

```
 '0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7'
```

I can do this with vim marcos, *reasonably* cutely, or knock up some python, but I'd like to do it from the command line. Can I get a recommended starting point?  I'm suspecting there's some sed magic that can be done but I can't get my head around it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash has a sequence operator that you can use:

```
sequence () { 
    read start finish <<< "${1/.../ }"
    start=${start//\'/}
    finish=${finish//\'/}
    eval echo {$start..$finish}
}
while read line; do
    sequence "$line"
done << END
'0'...'7' 
'0'...'9'
'a'...'j'
END
```

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a b c d e f g h i j
```

I have to use `eval` because bash will attempt to expand the sequence *before* it expands the variables. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sequences are always ascending;

```
$ cat input alphabet
'0'...'7'
'0'...'9'
'a'...'j'
0123456789abcdefghijklmiopqrstuvwxyzj

tr \'. '  ' <input  | 
while read f t ; do 
    grep -Po "$f.*?$t" alphabet;
done

01234567
0123456789
abcdefghij
```

This is probably a lot slower than the bash-eval version.